# How to write useEffect logic to close menu when URL changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I need to close the megamenu when the current URL changes. I am using Next.js 14. How can I write a `useEffect` statement?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
      setScrolling(true);
    } else {
      setScrolling(false);
    }
  };

  const handleUrlChange = () => {
    setSecondaryOpen(false); 
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleUrlChange);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleUrlChange);
  };
}, [router.events]);
```

Is this correct? It gave me:

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/vindy/works/skopeNewv2/nextjs/src/components/shared/Header/Header.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2339",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'events' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 54,
    "startColumn": 12,
    "endLineNumber": 54,
    "endColumn": 18
}]
```

Comment: What is `router` in your code example? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? Can you also verify for us what specific version of Next.js you are using so we can cross reference correct documentation?

Answer (score -1):

As of Next.js 12, the `router.events` API has been updated. The error message you're seeing is because `events` is no longer a property on the `router` object in Next.js 14. Instead, Next.js now uses a new set of APIs for handling router events. You will need to use the new API for `routeChangeComplete`.

Here is the updated useEffect hook that should work with Next.js 14:-

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

// Inside your component
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
      setScrolling(true);
    } else {
      setScrolling(false);
    }
  };

  const handleRouteChange = () => {
    setSecondaryOpen(false);
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  
  // Listen for route changes
  router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
  
  // Cleanup event listeners
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
  };
  
  // You should specify all variables used inside the useEffect as dependencies
}, [setScrolling, setSecondaryOpen, router]);
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your answer provides that is different from the OPs code other then  explicitly using the `useRouter` hook and changing the `useEffect` dependency. Otherwise it appears to be a copy/paste of the OP's code. Am I missing something here?

Comment: you are correct, I forgot to mention that we should specify all variables used inside the `useEffect` as dependencies. I updated the answer

Comment: Well, sure, there's always React best practices about hook dependencies, but I was referring more to your explanation about router events having changed  and no longer being on the `router` and that the code is the same as OPs and still references a `router.events`.